# Shared data and shared methods in .NET Core Razor

Tags: c#, razor, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I am new to C# and .NET and am about to create a little CRUD project based on .NET Core 2.1, EF 2.1 and Razor pages.

I have this very basic question:

I need some basic methods and some basic data in many of my cshtml.cs controllers and I want to create one central place to define them. Which is the recommended way to do that?

I envision one or more static classes with static properties to provide common data for the controllers, and with methods that can be used by all controllers.  But is this the recommended solution? And in which folder of the project should I place them? Any naming conventions would be appreciated too.

An example for central data I want to store is a dictionary of database errors like this:

```
    Dictionary<int, string> _sqlErrorTextDict = new Dictionary<int, string>
    {
        {547,
            "This operation failed because another data entry uses this entry."},
        {2601,
            "One of the properties is marked as Unique index and there is already an entry with that value."}
    };
```

An example for a central method would be code that receives a DB error exception object and creates a list of error text messages from it, ready to be displayed in any view.

Comment: if you are new why are you trying out the previews? you may never know what is by design and what are bugs. Although release may have bugs, the chances are more here

Comment: Too broad... so many different options and all depends on what you are trying to achieve. Do some tutorials, learn some things, and then choose the techniques that you think suit your needs best. We certainly can't answer it for you

Comment: @musefan: I have worked my way all through the EF Core tutorial, but they do not show a way. I have also spent an hour on searching for answers for my question. But I will try to make my question more specific by adding examples.

Comment: @NevilleNazerane: I just migrated to Preview 2 because I will need lazy loading for my project.

Comment: looks like what you are looking for is dependency injection. Also, try to stay away from static as far as possible. You can always have singletons if needed

Comment: I usually use a folder or add a new project to the solution called "services" where you can write classes to be used for those kind of purposes. Also you can use dependency injection, for repositories to the data storage for instance, and inject the interface to the repo into the controller constructor to be used by it's methods.

Comment: https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/repository-pattern-in-asp-net-core/

Comment: No one *needs* lazy-loading. More often than not, it leads to sloppy code that generates N+1 query problems. It's always better to eager or explicitly load your relationships.  Also, I would agree with @NevilleNazerane, that it's a bad idea to have your first foray on a preview release. Previews are for developers that are already familiar with the framework.

Comment: @ChrisPratt: I think you are going off-topic. I suggest that we focus on my original question or simply ignore it. This question is equally valid in context of 2.0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use singletons for this. Here is a simple implementation based on your example:

First, create a class for storing the values. Your class could have any definition you find fit for your values. I am using this structure to stay closest to your code:

```
class CommonData : Dictionary<int, string>
{

}
```

In your startup.cs class you could use this:

```
services.AddSingleton(new CommonData {
    {547,
        "This operation failed because another data entry uses this entry."},
    {2601,
        "One of the properties is marked as Unique index and there is already an entry with that value."}
});
```

If you have too much data and would like to reduce the code on this file, you an create an extension function for this.

Within your controllers (and other services), you can use dependency injection to access this data:

```
private readonly CommonData commonData;
public HomeController(CommonData commonData)
{
    this.commonData = commonData;
}
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. The combination of key terms "dependency injection" and "service.AddSingleton" together with your code examples led me to find all necessary documentation and a good solution for my problem. I think this is the perfect way to do it and I do not understand why commentators were considering my question "too broad" (and issued multiple close requests).

Comment: I am now actually using a CommonTools class, that holds the Dictionary data as a public readonly property as well as the commonly available methods that I need. May I ask the following additional questions: 1. Why did you send the Dictionary data through the constructor call instead of hard coding it into a public property of a CommonData class? Anything wrong about my approach of doing this? 2. Is there a recommended folder structure for service classes? I am using "/Services" in the root of my project right now.

Comment: 1. this completely depends on the purpose of `CommonTools` class. Usually, startup is where things like application settings are defined. Check the step 2 here for an example https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/identity. Startup file is also where you access your `IConfiguration`. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/. Although the `IConfiguration` can be used within any service if required.

Comment: 2. If your entire website is within a single project, then it is usually stored in "/Services" folder". You can create a new application using `dotnet new mvc -au Individual` in a new folder and check how this application is structured.

Comment: about 2.: with parameter "mvc" this will not create a Razor structure. With parameter "razor" it will. But none of the two options creates a "/Services" folder. They both seem to create the bare minimum of needed folders. It still would be great to have a best-practices folder structure. Any ideas?

Comment: I just tried `dotnet new mvc -au Individual` and found the `Services` folder. Regarding the razor part, in terms structure, everything except the controller folder should be the same. The rest are structures for .net core application.

Comment: Then this might be a difference (or a bug) in 2.1 Preview 2. I did both mvc and razor this morning and received the following root folder structures: for mvc --> Properties, wwwroot, Areas, Controllers, Data, Models, Views // for razor --> Properties, wwwroot, Areas, Data, Pages.